# React https image link working but local image link isn’t

Tags: reactjs, image, https, jpeg

I have an images.js file in React that imports data.

```
import { aData } from './aData';
```

I have a data.js file with the following code.

```
export const aData = [
  {
    image:
      'https://…'
  },
  {
    image:
      '.\images1\a.jpg'
  }
];
```

The jpg is in a folder inside the same folder as the images.js and aData.js files but while the https file displays, the jpg does not. These are the paths:

```
src\components\images1\a.jpg
src\components\images.js
src\components\aData.js
```

Comment: Is the image there in the path with the same name?

Comment: Inside the src folder there is a folder called components. Inside that are images.js, aData.js and a folder called images1. a.jpg is inside the images1 folder.

Comment: Try changing to
`{
    image:
      '.\components\images1\a.jpg'
  }`

Comment: I tried that but no joy. I also tried  { image:'.\images1\a.jpg'} and '.\components\images1\a.jpg'.

Comment: try changing the slash `{     image:       './components/images1/a.jpg'   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the slash
`{     image:       './components/images1/a.jpg'   }`

Comment: I did that and it worked.